# what is & mean in c++ lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda

```
if (n < 0) return 0;
std::vector<int> vec = {0,1,2,3};
if (n > 3) vec.resize(n+1, -1);
std::function<int(int)> fib = [&](int n)
{
    if (vec[n] == -1)
      vec[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    return vec[n];
};
return fib(n);
```

I know `[&](int n)` is a lambda which likes a block in Objctive-C, but what is `[&]` mean? What is the different between `[]`?

Comment: It is a capture clause. The `&` means to capture everything in the current scope and bring it into the `lambda`'s scope.

Comment: I think it would capture everything in the scope, in constrast with capturing nothing ([]). Read http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[&](int n) {}` means that in the lambda block you capture every variable from the scope by reference in contrast for example to `[=](int n) {}` where you have an access by value. You could also specify excactly what variable you need to be passed by reference or by value `[&a, b](int n) {}`

PS. Have a look on: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: what the different between `[&a](int n){}` and `[a](int n){}`?

Comment: in `[a](int n){}` modification of variable `a` won't take affect on the `a` variable from the scope.